# TS2304 with Webpack 2 and Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been following angular's [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) on how to use webpack 2 with angular 2. My code (github src [here](https://github.com/jdbriaris/angular-webpack)) is set up up with the `webpack.dev.js` scenario.

Running the dev build using `npm start` (i.e., `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080`) gives a series of `TS2304` errors, such as

```
ERROR in [at-loader] src\app\app.component.ts:5:15
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in [at-loader] src\app\app.component.ts:6:14
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Tried removing @types and use typings instead. Still get the same errors. Must be missing something simple....

Comment: So just cloned angular quickstart, and appears to be no problems building and running that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure you have installed `@types/node`.

then write `"types": ["jasmine","node"]` in `tsconfig.json` file
then this error will remove.

because same error is also facing by me. this solution is worked for me.

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": ["jasmine","node"]
  }
}
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpackCreator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Added that but no joy (I think the typescript compiler should pick them up by default). Are you able to post your `tsconfig.json` and possibly `package.json`? See if there are any differences - thnx.

Comment: So we now have identical `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` files, but I still get all these errors. Out of interest what version of `node` do you have installed?

Comment: currently i have node v6.9.1
and npm 3.10.8

Comment: could you please tell me where is tsconfig.json in app structure?
and have you got any tsconfig.json not found error in cmd?

Comment: No such error and `tsconfig.json` at top level, see [here](https://github.com/jdbriaris/angular-webpack). It's weird because I have no problems building the [angular quick seed](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

Comment: okie do last try go into config/webpack.common.js

 `options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }`

remove src from there.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure there is an `options: {...` property for webpack.

Comment: https://github.com/jdbriaris/angular-webpack/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L23

here

Comment: D'oh! You got me on the right path - I was pointing to `./src/tsconfig.json` when I should have been pointing to `./tsconfig.json` in that loader option. Also added option `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]` to `tsconfig.json` instead of `types:["jasmine","node"]` see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types). Both will work, but former more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You need Node.js typings.

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: Pretty sure I've got that, see my `package.json` [here](https://github.com/jdbriaris/angular-webpack/blob/master/package.json)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my tsconfig.json fixed it for me:

```
"typeRoots": [ 
    "../node_modules/@types/"
]
```

I ran into the issue following the Angular 2 Webpack Intro (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

The tsconfig.json code in the guide is different to the code in the 'final result' zip file (https://angular.io/resources/zips/webpack/webpack.zip)

Here's my whole tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "typeRoots": [ 
            "../node_modules/@types/"
        ]
    }
}
```